# How to maintain glibc and libmusl Python wheels in the same pip repository?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel, twine

Previously we've used our internal pip repository for source distributions only. Moving forward we want to host wheels as well to accomplish two things:

1. serve our own code to both (local) developer machines and Alpine Docker environments
2. create wheels for packages that don't have Alpine wheels

Unfortunately the wheels built with different libraries share the same artifact name and the second one gets rejected by the pip repository:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  build-alpine:
    build: alpine
    image: build-alpine-wheels
    volumes:
      - $PWD/cython:/build
    working_dir: /build
    command: sh -c 'python setup.py bdist_wheel && twine upload --repository-url http://pypi:8080 -u admin -p admin dist/*'

  build-debian:
    build: debian
    image: build-debian-wheels
    volumes:
      - $PWD/cython-debian:/build
    working_dir: /build
    command: bash -c 'sleep 10s && python setup.py bdist_wheel && twine upload --repository-url http://pypi:8080 -u admin -p admin dist/*'

  pypi:
    image: stevearc/pypicloud:1.0.2
    volumes:
      - $PWD/pypi:/etc/pypicloud/

  alpine-test:
    image: build-alpine-wheels
    depends_on:
      - build-alpine
    command: sh -c 'while ping -c1 build-alpine &>/dev/null;  do sleep 1; done; echo "build container finished" && pip install -i http://pypi:8080/pypi --trusted-host pypi cython && cython --version'

  debian-test:
    image: python:3.6
    depends_on:
      - build-debian
    command: bash -c 'while ping -c1 build-debian &>/dev/null;  do sleep 1; done; echo "build container finished" && pip install -i http://pypi:8080/pypi --trusted-host pypi cython && cython --version'
```

**alpine/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine

RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install twine
```

**debian/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install twine
```

**pypi/config.ini**

```
[app:main]
use = egg:pypicloud

pyramid.reload_templates = False
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en

pypi.default_read =
    everyone
pypi.default_write =
    everyone

pypi.storage = file
storage.dir = %(here)s/packages

db.url = sqlite:///%(here)s/db.sqlite

auth.admins =
  admin

user.admin = $6$rounds=535000$sFuRqMc5PbRccW1J$OBCsn8szlBwr4yPP243JPqomapgInRCUavv/p/UErt7I5FG4O6IGSHkH6H7ZPlrMXO1I8p5LYCQQxthgWZtxe1

# For beaker
session.encrypt_key = s0ETvuGG9Z8c6lK23Asxse4QyuVCsI2/NvGiNvvYl8E=
session.validate_key = fJvHQieaa0g3XsdgMF5ypE4pUf2tPpkbjueLQAAHN/k=
session.secure = False
session.invalidate_corrupt = true

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[uwsgi]
paste = config:%p
paste-logger = %p
master = true
processes = 20
reload-mercy = 15
worker-reload-mercy = 15
max-requests = 1000
enable-threads = true
http = 0.0.0.0:8080
virtualenv = /env

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, botocore, pypicloud

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_pypicloud]
level = DEBUG
qualname = pypicloud
handlers =

[logger_botocore]
level = WARN
qualname = botocore
handlers =

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)s %(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(message)s
```

**Setup and execution**

```
git clone https://github.com/cython/cython
git clone https://github.com/cython/cython cython-debian
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

At the end I would like both test containers to be able to execute `cython --version`. Which works for the Alpine container:

```
alpine-test_1   | Collecting cython
alpine-test_1   | Downloading http://pypi:8080/api/package/cython/Cython-0.29.12-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl (5.0MB)
alpine-test_1   | Installing collected packages: cython
alpine-test_1   | Successfully installed cython-0.29.12
alpine-test_1   | Cython version 0.29.12
```

But doesn't work for the Debian container:

```
debian-test_1   | Downloading http://pypi:8080/api/package/cython/Cython-0.29.12-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl (5.0MB)
debian-test_1   | Installing collected packages: cython
debian-test_1   | Successfully installed cython-0.29.12
debian-test_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
debian-test_1   |   File "/usr/local/bin/cython", line 6, in <module>
debian-test_1   |     from Cython.Compiler.Main import setuptools_main
debian-test_1   |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 28, in <module>
debian-test_1   |     from .Scanning import PyrexScanner, FileSourceDescriptor
debian-test_1   | ImportError: libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I find it particularly curious that both environments try to pull this wheel because there are all sorts of packages which don't work with Alpine (e.g. Pandas) in which case pip goes straight for the source distribution. I suppose I must be doing something wrong in that regard as well.

So now I'm wondering how I can create these wheels such that for each version of the software package two different wheels can live in the pip repository and have pip automatically download and install the correct one.

Comment: For `glibc`-based distros, build `manylinux1` wheels. For Alpine, the easiest way is to build the platform-specific wheels (`linux_x86_64`) and then rename them, e.g. `mypkg-1.0+musl-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl`, when use `pip install mypkg-1.0+musl` for Alpine-based stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no support for musl in the `manylinux` standard: your options are to always build from source, or target a different, glibc-based platform.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that now PEP656 defines a platform tag 'musllinux'
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0656/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using Alpine at all—you can get images almost as small with multi-stage builds (https://pythonspeed.com/articles/smaller-python-docker-images/), and musl doesn't just mean lack of binary wheels. There's a whole bunch of production bugs people have had due to musl (Python crashes, timestamp formatting problems—see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/ for references).

Most of the known musl links have been fixed, but it's different enough that it doesn't seem worth the production risk (not to mention your very expensive developer time!) just to get a 100MB-smaller image.